Composer Install - asset-packagist.org 404 not found error
I added the asset-packagist.org as one of my composer packages for my Drupal project.
     "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    },

I'm encountering random or intermittent errors like this.
    > DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
    Loading composer repositories with package information

    In CurlDownloader.php line 640:

    The "https://cdn.asset-packagist.org/p/provider-latest/8799ec77a377378f0d0e6f
    2671a922763cf91959dda43f6df69c6b11b025d75d.json" file could not be downloaded 
    (HTTP/2 404 )


    install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] 
    [--dry-run] [--download-only] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] 
    [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [--audit] 
    [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] 
    [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] 
    [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] 
    [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] 
    [<packages>...]

Anyone have an idea?

The following command fix the error for me: Run this command on the CLI before installing any dependencies. It forces composer to use https to download all resources:
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org

Source: How to correct the [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] error for composer

asset-packagist.org and packagist.org are different.
